# Priority queue implementation

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparable

I was trying to build a priority queue but there seems to be some inconsistency when I tested it. I overrode method `compareTo()` but somehow it return student with the youngest age. Why is that ? Shouldn't it be the student with age 22 (highest) ? Here is the code:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

   private String name;
   private int age;

   public Student(int i) {
      age = i;
   }
   public int getAge(){
    return this.age;
   }

   public int print(){
    return age; 
   }
   @Override
   public int compareTo(Student s) {
    if(this.age < s.getAge()){return -1;}
    else if(this.age > s.getAge()){return 1;}
    else{return 0;}
   }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<Student> q = new PriorityQueue<Student>();
        q.offer(new Student(21));
        q.offer(new Student(18));
        q.offer(new Student(22));

        Student s = q.poll();
        System.out.println(s.print());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's `java.util.PriorityQueue` is defined as returning the least element, not the largest element, as you can find by checking the docs.

> The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the
>   specified ordering. If multiple elements are tied for least value, the
>   head is one of those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily. The
>   queue retrieval operations poll, remove, peek, and element access the
>   element at the head of the queue.

Whether a priority queue is based on a minimum or maximum depends on the language and library, but minimum queues are by fat the most common from what I've seen.

Comment: Can we Implementing priority queue with hash table please?